# How do I interpret and resolve "dyld: Symbol not found ..."

Tags: c++, macos-sierra, dylib

So I run into the following error when trying to run a basic test program that links to an external library (uWS - https://github.com/uWebSockets/uWebSockets):

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _uv_loop_new
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libuWS.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _uv_loop_new
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libuWS.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

I've found a bunch of other questions and answers related to very similar issues, but they just talk about the library being referenced (in this case `libuWS.dylib`) not being able to find it's dependencies. I've checked it's dependencies with `otool -L libuWS.dylib` and they all exist where they should.

I noticed that all the other examples of the error had "expected in" as the library that was missing, which makes sense. I'm just not too sure what `flat namespace` means, and how I can make sure the symbol is found in it?

The project is build with CLion using the compiler installed with Xcode (I didn't change any settings here, so I guess whatever is the default.. pretty new to coding on macOS, sorry!)

Any pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I haven't provided enough information.

Comment: You may need to set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, e.g. `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib` (or even just `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` if you don't have anything in `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to start with). This assumes the .dylib containing `_uv_loop_new` is in that same `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: I remember trying something with `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` yesterday when I was researching.. what should I have in it? It's currently empty and to be honest I don't remember clearing it, but I was pretty tired when I first came across this issue!

Comment: Sorry @PaulR, didn't notice your edit! That's the thing.. I have no idea which lib contains `_uv_loop_new` because it just says it expects it in `flat namespace`, which I have no clue about.

EDIT: I also just added both /usr/lib and /usr/local/lib to `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and it's still complaining with the same error

Comment: Ah - looks like it's not a .dylib, just a static library - you may just need `-luv` (and perhaps an appropriate `-L<whatever>`) - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18816428/253056).

Comment: Nail on the head! Cheers mate, that's got it working :)